# hyperledger fabric arquitecture issues

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I've been recently assign the task to manage a Hyperledger Fabric network and investigate several issues related to timeouts. The problems occur somewhat randomly rendering the related application to simply fail. The only workaround at the moment has been to "delay" the transactions. Seems the network is not able to handle concurrency requests at all at times. Sometimes the network just stop running and the only fix to restore from backups!

The fatal error is:

```
connectToSomeEndpoint -> Could not connect to any endpoint of ... (list of orderers)
```

As a result I'm doing a full review of the network architecture and found the following design:

[image]

It seems wrong to me to have Orderer and Peer node under same organizations. And in addition to that, i'm not sure how the orderers interact among themselves by being each one on a different org.

Should I just plan to change the entire architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems unlikely those are all CA servers. The (IBM) recommendation is a CA Server per node. (1 for each Peer and 1 for each Orderer). The names make no sense as CA servers.

Is it Kafka or Raft? In any event,only 1 Orderer is the leader. The others are for failover.

Those org names are from the testnet. Not really designed for robustness. Really only designed for a developer to use to write the chaincode.

I have seen similar when a network is running on VMs and not used for some time period. The VMs may get shut down and on restart they don't correctly restart all containers.

Comment: That is exactly the scenario i'm dealing with. The network is running on VM's. The configuration is RAFT.

Comment: Yes, I'm not really sure how the orderer works being part of the application orgs, and not having it's own org and only having each one of them 1 node.

Comment: The concept of Org is, IMHO, quite confusing or misleading. IBM mostly uses Org to mean a Peer. With the assumption that an actual entity only has 1 Peer. Orderers are not typically referred to as an Org. But in the standard testnet deployment, it has it's own CA server. So an entity might have 3 Peers. They might use 1 or 3 CA servers. (1 for all Peers or 1 per Peer). What really matters is who controls the CA Servers. In testnet, there are 4 nodes (3 peers and 1 Orderer) each with it's own CA Server. In development using testnet this would likely be 1 actual entity controlling all 4 nodes.

Comment: There is a bit of an assumption that an Orderer would not belong to the same entity as any of the 3 Peer nodes. But in a real network, you might have 3 entities, each with 1 Peer and each with 1 Orderer. The Orderers constantly communicate and elect a Leader which does all the ordering. The others being failover or I notice fairly regular re-election to make Orderer 2 leader for a while, then Orderer 3, etc. But only one actually does the ordering at any time. I've built networks all different ways and they all work. Just needs to match your desired entities participating in the network.

Comment: There is less of a need to have failover orderers if you use k8s, as that should generally decrease risk of failure. But, I had a network with only 1 Orderer and it ran out of disk space and was a lot of trouble. k8s and keep good orderer backups is the most common configuration, I think. It is immaterial who actually controls the CA server for the Orderer, except for network participant desires. To be really safe, this would not be any of the Peer entities. Note: the Orderer makes no consensus decisions on transactions to include in a block. Only the order of the transactions within a block.